# Printing only certain rows in a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file that contains a date of birth field similar to this:

```
John,Smith,34 La La Lane,14/03/85,johnsmith@email.com
Sarah,Second,42 Wallaby Way,11/06/92,sarahsecond@email.com
Third,Example,99 Peacock Terrace,04/12/89,thirdexample@email.com
```

And I want to make a program that only prints rows in the file of entries born during a certain month (in this case the month is after the first slash, ie. dd/mm/yy).

So, if the desired month was March, it'd print off John Smith's entry.

Any help on this would be great, I've been struggling for a while

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt at a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of the problem you're struggling with, so I'll give a somewhat general answer. Python has a csv reader you can use like this:

```
import csv
desiredMonth = 3
with open('people.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in content:
        month = int(row[3].split('/')[1])
        if month == desiredMonth:
            # print the row or store it in a list for later printing
```

`row` will already be separated out for you into a list, so `row[3]` will be the birthday. `split()` then separates the month portion into pieces, and `[1]` gives the second piece, which is the month. Converting it to `int` is a good idea so you can easily compare it to whatever month you want.

Comment: My main issue was regarding splitting the month. Could you please explain that portion of the code further?

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Edited to give more detail on that

Comment: For even a marginally more complicated filter, you'll probably want to use `datetime` to parse the date into and object… but for this case, `split` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach...For working with csv files, the python package `csvkit` installs a number of command-line utilities that let you slice and dice your .csv files really easily.

```
$ pip install csvkit
```

This will install a command called `csvgrep` (among others).

```
$ csvgrep -c 4 -r '\d{2}/03' yourfile.csv
First,Last,Address,Birthdate,Email
John,Smith,34 La La Lane,14/03/85,johnsmith@email.com
```

One thing to note is that the `csvkit` assumes all .csv files have header rows. That's why the result of the `csvgrep` shows a header row. That also means that you will have to add a header to your data file like this:

```
First,Last,Address,Birthdate,Email
John,Smith,34 La La Lane,14/03/85,johnsmith@email.com
Sarah,Second,42 Wallaby Way,11/06/92,sarahsecond@email.com
Third,Example,99 Peacock Terrace,04/12/89,thirdexample@email.com
```

Explanation of command-line args:

```
$ csvgrep -c 4 -r '\d{2}/03' yourfile.csv
-c specifies which column you want to search 
-r specifies the regular expression you want to match in the column
```

The regex '^\d{2}/03' will match a string that starts with 2 digits, then a '/', then the month '03'.

Check out the [csvkit tutorial](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/getting_started.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        date = row[3]
        month = date.split('/')[1]
        if int(month) >= YOUR_MONTH_HERE
            print row
```

Comment: Missing semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

As much tutorial type as I could put into it :-)

```
somecsvfile=r'/home/me/Desktop/txt.csv'
the_month_you_are_looking_for = 6 # as in june.
with open(somecsvfile, 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:   
        list_from_text = line.split(',')
        bday = list_from_text[3]
        bmonth = int(bday.split('/')[1])
        if bmonth == the_month_you_are_looking_for:
            print (line)
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything over goron's answer except for a bunch of mistakes (e.g., `for line in fi.readlines():` instead of `for line in fi:`, opening the file `'r'` instead of `'rb'`, etc.) and trying to do manual CSV parsing instead of using `csv`.